# TF no gradients for variable or no gradient flow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to compute gradients for the trainable parameters of convolution filter shape. The part of the code of generating the filter shape from the `tf.Variable` seems to work fine. But when I'm trying to compute gradients I see that they are `None` for corresponding `tf.Variable` and if I apply these `None` gradients I get `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable`. It seems that I have no gradient flow somehow. I can not get why. Suggestions please?

Code to recreate the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def mean_filter2d_p(image, filter_shape=(3, 3), name=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name or "mean_filter2d"):
        image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, name="image")

        rank = image.shape.rank
        if rank != 3 and rank != 4:
            raise ValueError("image should be either 3 or 4-dimensional.")

        # Expand to a 4-D tensor
        if rank == 3:
            image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

        area = tf.cast(filter_shape[0] * filter_shape[1], dtype=tf.float32)
        filter_shape = tf.concat([filter_shape, [tf.shape(image)[-1], 1]], axis=-1)
        kernel = tf.ones(shape=filter_shape, dtype=image.dtype) / area

        output = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(image, kernel, strides=(1, 1, 1, 1), padding="SAME")

        if rank == 3:
            output = tf.squeeze(output, axis=0)

        return output

def highpass_median_p(images, filter_shape=(3, 3)):
    blurred = mean_filter2d_p(image=images, filter_shape=filter_shape)
    subtracted = images - blurred

    return subtracted, images, blurred

resolution = 128
img = tf.ones([1, resolution, resolution, 3])


filter_shapew = tf.Variable([3.0 / 128.0, 3.0 / 128.0], trainable=True, name='filter_shape')


with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

    filter_shape = tf.math.sigmoid(filter_shapew * tf.cast(resolution, dtype=tf.float32), name='filter_shape_clip')
    filter_shape = tf.math.minimum(tf.cast(filter_shape, dtype=tf.int32) + 1, resolution)

    x, x_o, x_b = highpass_median_p(img, filter_shape)

    loss_value = 1.0 - tf.reduce_mean(tf.reshape(x, [-1]))
    print(loss_value)

grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, filter_shapew)
print(grads)
```

Comment: Hi @HackSaw! Could you let us know your Tensorflow version as I did not get any error in [2.8.2](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/mohantym/e42f1b5a0221ef17a67b788a31e83ba1/stack_73517419.ipynb)  version . W.r.to  above error , I can say the loss value has to be a differential function ( no exploding gradient or zero gradient), You can square function or use visualisation tool to see your function and smoothen it to make it differentiable one.